# Need RegEx to validate the string contains two words or more (not a comparison)

Tags: php, regex

The input string must be at least two words.  No other restrictions (for example, minimum two characters followed by a space or comma).

I'm fine validating to find at least two word strings, but I also need to accept three word, four word strings, five words.......

Googled for days, keep coming up with only two word answers (string contains two words max).

Comment: How about: `\w+(?:[, ]\w+)+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match:

- a word boundary,
- followed by a word,
- another boundary,
- anything else,
- another word,
- another boundary.

```
\b\w+\b.*\w+\b
```